# 220v heater in garage

Tags: garage, 240v, heater

I currently have a 50 amp 220 breaker in my breaker box and a 50 amp outlet in the garage(I think it used to have a washer and dryer).  I bought a garage heater that is 20 amp so the plug doesn't match.  Can I just change the outlet or should I also change the breaker?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the outlet box please?

Answer (score 1):

- Breaker must be the right size for the wire *or smaller*.
- Breaker must be the right size for the receptacle - normally a one-to-one correspondence, but there are a couple of specific exceptions.
- Breaker must be the right size as specified by the connected equipment.

In your case, this means you need to do one of the following:

- Replace the breaker with a 20A breaker and replace the receptacle with a 20A receptacle. You will likely need to pigtail wires at the receptacle as a 20A receptacle will normally take 12 AWG and probably 10 AWG (good for up to 30A) wires but not 6 AWG (for 50A).
- Subpanel time! 50A is enough to power a subpanel. That would allow you to connect multiple 15A, 20A, 30A, etc. circuits, both 120V and 240V.

You stated 220V and tagged 240V. That could be Europe (or anywhere) where 220V/230V/240V is the primary voltage in residential use. But I suspect you are in US/Canada where we use a split 120V/240V system - 120V for small stuff and 240V for big stuff. A key question is *neutral*. If your existing circuit did not include neutral then a heater (simple 240V heater normally doesn't a neutral) will be fine but additional circuits, particularly 120V circuits, will be a big problem. However, if your existing circuit includes a neutral then a full subpanel will work great, allowing you to power 120V, 240V and 120V/240V circuits. That is a major project compared to replacing one receptacle, but if you have other plans for the garage - e.g., if the heater is so you can use it as additional workspace that in turn requires power tools, etc., or if you are considering EV charging, then a subpanel is a wise investment.

Comment: Wow.  I am really impressed with not only how fast people responded, but how thorough the answers are.  I will be calling an electrician to do the breaker work.  Thanks everyone...

Comment: @BobPinta if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to up vote every answer that helps you and to select the check mark next to the one that helps the _most_.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the breaker (as well as the receptacle) to the correct size. A 50A breaker will support all sorts of arcs, sparks and general mayhem in the event of a failure of some part of your heater that a 20A breaker would trip for.

There's also the code rule of following the instructons of the heater, which surely are telling you to use a 20A breaker.

In the long run (yes, more cost upfront, no doubt) a cold climate minisplit will cost you **much less to run** for the same heat output. Thus, over the long run, it will cost you much less overall. Resistance heat is cheap on upfront cost, expensive to run.